# Clicking on item two times instead on one

Tags: java, bukkit

I got a gui and when I click on material coal I need to click on it again to get it to activate the code. 
Here is my inventoryclickevent

```
    String stripname = ChatColor.stripColor(e.getClickedInventory().getName());
    if(stripname.equals("Upgrade Spawner".toUpperCase())) 
    {
        if(e.getCursor()!=null) 
        {
            if(e.getCursor().getType()!=null) 
            {
                Material item = e.getCursor().getType();
                if(item.equals(Material.STAINED_GLASS_PANE)) e.setCursor(null);
                else if(item.equals(Material.COAL))
                {
                    if(checkBalance(e.getWhoClicked(), config.getInt("Coal Cost"))) 
                    {
                        takeAwayMoney(e.getWhoClicked(), config.getInt("Coal Cost"));
                        e.getWhoClicked().closeInventory();
                        e.getWhoClicked().sendMessage(ChatColor.GREEN + "Iron Golems now drop coal!");
                    } else 
                    {
                        e.getWhoClicked().closeInventory();
                        e.getWhoClicked().sendMessage(ChatColor.RED + "You do not have the requirment amount of money! You need " + getMoneyNeeded(e.getWhoClicked(), config.getInt("Coal Cost")) + " more!");
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Have you stepped through the code with your IDE debugger?  What did you find?

Comment: What is the IDE debugger?

Comment: The debugger is where you run the code one line at a time to see where it fails or where values change; it helps you know where something might be going wrong. What software are you using to write your code?

Comment: I am using Eclipse

Answer (score 1):

Because `getCursor` returns item that player is holding in the cursor and you are checking if it is not null - so first click will move that item to cursor, and then on next click cursor will not be null and code will execute.
Use `getCurrentItem` instead.